# Vue 3 - Optimising Javascript/Typescript form validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs3

I've been practising with JavaScript/Typescript and I just did a form validator for a contact form in Vue 3. I really feel as though the code I implemented may not really be considered an industry standard and particularly not well written. Can anyone kindly suggest or show ways this validator can be refactored and perhaps also optimised?

Form.vue - I won't be showing the html not to add too much clutter to the question.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {defineComponent, PropType, ref, watch} from "vue";

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'Form',
        setup(props) {
            const name = ref("");
            const email = ref("");
            const telNumber = ref("");
            const message = ref("");    
            const emailFailure = ref(false);

            // Validation errors
            const nameError = ref(false);
            const emailRequired = ref(false);
            const emailError = ref(false);

            // Phone number formatting
            watch(telNumber, (value) => {
                if (value) {
                    telNumber.value =   telNumber.value.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g, '($1) $2-$3');
                }
            })

            // Run validate form to check whether the data is added
            function validateForm() {
                if (name.value === '') {
                    nameError.value = true;
                } else {
                    nameError.value = false;
                }
                if (email.value === '') {
                    emailRequired.value = true;
                } else {
                    emailRequired.value = false;
                }
                if (!validEmail(email.value) && email.value !== '') {
                    emailError.value = true;
                } else {
                    emailError.value = false;
                }
                if (nameError.value || emailRequired.value || emailError.value) {
                    AnalyticsHandler.userSendForm(true);
                } else if (!nameError.value && !emailRequired.value && !emailError.value) { 
                    sendEmail();
                } 
            }

            // check if the email is valid
            function validEmail(email: any) {
                const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email.trim());
        }

            return {
                name,
                email,
                telNumber,
                message,
                validateForm,
                nameError,
                emailError,
                emailFailure,
                emailRequired,
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not use a library like Vuelidate? [v2](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app) has support for VueJS v3.

Comment: I had a brief look at these libraries but for this scenario I preferred to do it a bit more raw.